# Is it possible to achieve this flexible layout without using JS?

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to achieve without using JS can be seen on [jsfiddle.net/k2h5b/](http://jsfiddle.net/k2h5b/4/).

Basically I would like to display two images, both centered, one in **background** and one in **foreground**:

- **Background Image**: Should **cover the whole window** without affecting the aspect ratio, which means that the image will always touch two opposite edges of the window, but the image **will be cropped**.
- **Forground Image**: Should be **inside the window** without affecting the aspect ratio, which means the image will be always touch two opposite edges of the window, but the image **will not be cropped**.
- It doesn't matter if it's a `<div>` or an `<img>` tag, as long as they are displaying the images.
- Asume also that the image sizes are known upfront and can be used in CSS or HTML part.

So my question is: is it possible using only CSS or CSS3?

If it's not possible I will accept the answer that will be as close as possible to my goal.

### Examples:

- When the **background image** is cropped from the top and bottom: [image: example when background image is cropped from top and the bottom]
- When the **background image** when it's cropped from left and right: [image: example when background image is cropped from left and right]

Comment: Sorry about the long image links (I fixed them now if you want to use the same ones), it's because the original example was created by @tzador (http://stackoverflow.com/users/165697/tzador)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at @Kent Brewster's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971763/is-it-possible-to-achieve-this-flexible-layout-without-using-js/7972220#7972220), I think I could achieve all the requirements of OP.

This doesn't have the problem of foreground image being cropped and you can also specify constant margin around the foreground image. Also `div` is being used instead of `img` tag, because we are using background images.  Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/lipis/k2h5b/17/) and here is the code:

```
<div id='bg'></div>
<div id='fg'></div>

#bg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/iOvxJ.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
#fg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  opacity: .7;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/HP9tp.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: I see what you did there.. even thought it's looks ok.. the overhead of cutting the images is not the best ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<html>
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#bg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent url(bg.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#fg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  background: transparent url(fg.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: .7;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="bg"></div>
<div id="fg"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If the scaling requirement is flexible, it might work.  See http://jsfiddle.net/k2h5b/5/ to see it run.

Comment: He also wants it to resize though. It's more than just the positioning.

Comment: I don't see any resizing in the screen shots.

Comment: +1 For using `background-size`. But it needs `background-size: contain;` on the `#fg` element, like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/k2h5b/6/).

Comment: Its good, uses some advanced background css properties, but if u make it very wide and small height, it cuts the foreground eagle.

Comment: yes.. after playing more with it I can see that the foreground image is being cropped.. which is not the optimal.. the main goal is to have that image being shown all the time and as good as it gets for the background.

Comment: Hey Kent I updated my answer, using what I learned from your post if you want to check it out

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [it's possible](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/k2h5b/1/).

Basically I just made the background image the background for the `<body>` (doesn't have to be the body of course), and then put the image inside that with a small margin.

```
<body>
  <img id='fg' src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-OYlUbWqyqog/TeL-gXGx3MI/AAAAAAAAHRc/bdqvvvaeC7c/s1600/bald-eagle3.jpg'></img>
</body>
```

css:

```
body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('http://wallpaper.zoda.ru/bd/2006/07/21/2c7b4306fd22f049f331d43adb74a5f7.jpg') no-repeat left top;
}

#fg {
  margin: 20px 20px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

obviously if the window is too big, there'd be issues.  You could (I guess) use media queries to pull in different image sizes based on window size.

*edit* — OK, well for the image, if you *do* want it to crop and retain the right aspect ratio, then I think you'll have to know the image size ahead of time to do it so that it works out.  Lacking that, [here's another revision](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-OYlUbWqyqog/TeL-gXGx3MI/AAAAAAAAHRc/bdqvvvaeC7c/s1600/bald-eagle3.jpg).

```
<body>
  <div id='fg'>&nbsp;</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('http://wallpaper.zoda.ru/bd/2006/07/21/2c7b4306fd22f049f331d43adb74a5f7.jpg') no-repeat left top;
}

body, html { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

#fg {
  margin: 2%; width: 96%; height: 96%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background: url('http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-OYlUbWqyqog/TeL-gXGx3MI/AAAAAAAAHRc/bdqvvvaeC7c/s1600/bald-eagle3.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}
```

If you know the image dimensions, you could then set max-height and max-width.  (I'll try that too :-)

*edit again* To get the background to crop in a centered way, you'd need to set the position to "center center" instead of "left top".  (Or "center top" if you just want it centered horizontally.)

Vertically centering elements with CSS without cutting-edge non-standard features (flexible box layout) is hard.  That may be something to do with JavaScript.  I'll say that one problem with any JavaScript solution like that is that it *really* slows the browser down. If you must do it, I would suggest introducing a little time lag so that you don't try to recompute the layout on *every* resize event. Instead, set a timer for like 200 milliseconds in the future where the work will get done, and each time you do so cancel the previous timer. That way, while a person is dragging the window corner it won't burn up their CPU.

*edit even more* ooh ooh yes @Kent Brewster's answer with the vertical centering is good - I always forget that trick :-)

Comment: Well, it doesn't react as I wanted. Check my example and you'll see that you can always see at least one full dimension of the background and the whole foreground image..

Comment: Neither the background nor foreground in your example behave the same way as in OP's fiddle.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the second part - I though they'd both be cropped. I do think that the background is fine. Give me a sec.

Comment: The background is not fine either because I can always see only the top/left corner of the image.

Comment: Ah well then I think I can do that too :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve this effect using only CSS, for two main reasons:

1. Because you are trying to resize your image, you cannot use the `background` property and must instead use an `<img>` tag. Your image will always try to take up as much room as it can if the width and height are not set. Thus, the **aspect ratio** will not be maintained, or your image will be cropped.
2. The other caveat of resizing the image is that you will not be able to vertically-align it to the center of your page without knowing its dimensions.

Comment: I don't mind using an <img> tag. Whatever it takes.. and let's asume that image sizes are known upfront and I could use them in CSS. Does that helps at all or it still not possible..?

Comment: An `<img>` tag won't work for your resizing because it cannot maintain aspect ratio for both width and height. You _can_ maintain one without having the other though, by setting `width: 100%` or `height: 100%`.  

In terms of vertically aligning, it's not a matter of knowing the image's initial dimensions, but rather knowing the dimensions that the image would have once it starts resizing.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer really is too easy. Especially when OP adds the CSS3 tag which provides the background-size style. Not worth a downvote, but certainly not worthy of an upvote. -1

Comment: NGLN - I was assuming he wanted cross-browser compatibility and wasn't really looking into a CSS3 solution. robertc - how?

Comment: Because you can resize background images with CSS and you can also vertically align background images.

Comment: If you're willing to accept [60% browser support](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts), sure, but I definitely don't see that as an acceptable solution.

Comment: check @tzador answer.. it is possible :)